# Is it possible to use a var in a URLRequest

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, urlrequest

During development I have to test using several different hosts. It is a pain to have to change the IP address everywhere I use navigateToURL or in an mx:HTTPService.

I would like to set a var with the IP...

```
public var hostIP:String = "192.168.1.100";
```

Then later I instead of doing...

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest('http://192.161.1.100/JudgesRegistration.html?email='+email+'&password='+password),'_self')
```

I would like to do something like...

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest('http://'+hostIP+'/JudgesRegistration.html?email='+email+'&password='+password),'_self')
```

Then I would only have to change the IP assigned to hostIP instead of throughout the project. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to imbed the var in the URL string. Is this even possible?

Here is what my HTTPService looks like...

```
<mx:HTTPService 
    id="emailPasswordService"
    method="POST"
    url="http://192.168.1.100/chaos/emailPassword?output=xml"
    makeObjectsBindable="true"
    result="emailPasswordSuccess(event)"
    fault="httpServiceFaultHandler(event)"
    showBusyCursor="true"
    resultFormat="e4x">
</mx:HTTPService>
```

Thanks,

John

Comment: your URL is wrong: you need // after the http:  Otherwise, I see no reason this shouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should simply just work.

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest('http://' + hostIP + '/JudgesRegistration.html?email=' + email + '&password=' + password),'_self')
```

Are you finding any errors?

Comment: I'm sorry. I just tried it again in navigateToURL and it worked, but I am still not having success with the var in an HTTP:Service. URL="http://"+hostIP+"/blah/blah" will not build. I get "Element type "mx:HTTPService" must be followed by either attribute specifications, "." or "/>". Can I use the var in the HTTP:Service?

Comment: I added an example HTTPService to my question.As in the navigateToURL, I am trying to replace the 192.168.1.100 with the var.

Comment: Ok I got it. URL="http://{hostIP}/blah/blah" works! I also had to make hostIP [Bindable]

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are looking for are static class constants. You can declare a class that has constants which are accessible everywhere in your project.

```
package <any location you want>
{
    public class HostInfos
    {
        // static constants
        public static const HOST_IP:String = "192.168.1.100";

        public function HostInfos() {}
    }
}
```

Once you have a class like that, you can call the HOST_IP constant anywhere and retrieve its value. Ex.:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest('http://' + HostInfos.HOST_IP + '/JudgesRegistration.html?email='+email+'&password='+password),'_self')
```

Comment: Sorry, I put my edit in the wrong place. Hope it does not go through as I can not remove it.